# Можно ли сделать raw-сокет на прием и на передачу?

Tags: c, сеть, сокет, сокеты

Для raw-сокета на прием я использую `конфигурацию1`

```
m_recvFd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
```

а для сокета на отправку `конфигурацию2`

```
m_sendFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

Это приходится делать, потому что если пытаться отправить пакет с `конфигурацией1`, то этого не происходит. И в обратную сторону - если принять на сокет с `конфигурацией2`, то этого не проихсодит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие настройки для сокета нужно применять, чтобы он мог как принимать, так и отправлять пакеты.

Comment: *"если пытаться отправить пакет с конфигурацией1, то этого не происходит"* - подобные заявления следует подкреплять, приводя [mcve]